# Do we have data about how elders use QR codes?

Tags: user-behavior, older-users

I'm designing an app, and someone has defined that they want the user to login using a QR code in their mobiles and show them in a camera, that will recognise them and allow them to access.

Our persona is an elder woman, from 60 to 80, not very comfortable with technology. And I'm pretty scared that users will drop if they don't understand the flow:

1.Open the app
2.Locate the QR
3.Show it to the camera.

So, do we have data about how elder users use QR's? (In my company user testing it's not well recieved, so unfortunately we can't make test)

Thanks!

Comment: Very good question. I have no data but I bet no one uses it considering the QR code should also have low use through youngs.

Comment: @BraDev it's different if you are explicitly told to do so. But ask this: how many people use (or even know of) Messenger's code-scanning feature?

Comment: @BraDev The QR code is used a lot in Asian countries. Take a look at https://uqr.me/qr-code-generator/blog/qr-codes-in-asia-why-the-obsession/

Comment: My observation of users in waiting rooms here in the UK is that the 60-70 year olds are happily using smartphones and tablets.  Tablets have been around and affordable for 7-10 years so users in their 50s can have learnt how to use them.  It's the generation who are 10 years older ( so now 70-80) who are less likely to have "grown up with computers".

Comment: @BraDev Thanks :) My doubt about "No one uses it" increased when I readed some articles telling that the use of Qrs is increasing, but still I wanted to check the behavior of older people https://blog.beaconstac.com/2019/02/why-2019-is-the-year-of-qr-codes/

Comment: @KevinM. Thanks for that! I'm gonna update the post to add more details about the location of our client, we work essentially with american and sudamerican people, I bet there should be some differences with asians. (but if I'm wrong my problem should be solved!)

Comment: @PhillipW That makes sense, I'm gonna try to look a little bit more closer to our client, to see the range of ages. Thank you!

Comment: The best chance is to look at countries that have a very high usage of QR codes like China, and maybe you will find some information or research (academic papers or published online on websites). Sorry to hear that user testing is not well received in your company :(

Comment: I still don't understand the complete flow: After (3) "show QR to camera", what happens? Do you want them to login to a website on the desk/laptop, or to a website/app on the mobile?

Comment: The problem appears that there is too much work needed from the user. For starters, why does the user even need to know about QR codes? I'd design the physical interface as a physical slot in which the user would insert his phone, with an arrow showing the way. The same arrow should appear on the phone, so the symbols match up. And the QR code is embedded in the stem of the arrow. "Matching symbols" is a task we give to two-year olds. The fact that's a QR symbol should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

I found some statistics from Comscore, [14 Million Americans Scanned QR Codes on their Mobile Phones in June 2011](https://www.comscore.com/Insights/Press-Releases/2011/8/14-Million-Americans-Scanned-QR-or-Bar-Codes-on-their-Mobile-Phones-in-June-2011?cs_edgescape_cc=BR). The article is a bit old, but I think it is still relevant.

> A demographic analysis of those who scanned a QR code with their mobile phone in June revealed an audience that was more likely to be male, young to middle-age and upper income. Men were 25 percent more likely (index of 125) than the average mobile user to scan QR codes, representing 60.5 percent of the scanning audience.

Elderly people represented only 3% of the audience.

Comment: I'd guess that this statistic is less relevant than you might think. At least in germany there was a peak at about 2010-2012 according to the visibility on the streets. Nowadays there gone, you need some effort to find one. One of the reasons is of course the regression of usage.

Comment: @chrisbergr this is an interesting observation, and I wonder what caused the decline in usage in Germany whereas in China it is very common place these days.

Comment: @MichaelLai I'd guess that the situation in china is a result of the success story of WeChat. I mean you can do everything with it, even payments. Combined with QR codes this is a very powerful tool. There is nothing like this in Germany. In 2013 there war a official warning against the usage of QR codes from a Federal Ministry (Link is down). There was so much abuse around like linking to viruses etc. The trust was gone. Unfortunately, because it is such a helpfull thing, at least since it is a default build in into the iphone camera.

Answer (score 2):

Do we have any data about **how** everyone uses QR's?

> And I'm pretty scared that users will drop if they don't understand the flow

This is valid for any age group, my parents are the late 50s and they wouldn't know how to use QR code. You will never find out how good your ideas are if you don't test them out. Without a test, any statistics are just numbers and you are doing guesswork.

> In my company user testing it's not well received, so, unfortunately, we can't make test

I think this is the most common excuse for designers to hide behind (believe me I been there and said pretty much the same). Nothing stops you from creating prototypes and testing with friends and family, people in the cafes even on the streets, you will be surprised how much people will be interested also how much you will learn.